# Why this function doesn't return the value? - Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In the actions of my controller I often select a row from a table in the database by its id, so I separated this to a function. But every time when I do this I make a check if something was returned by the query, so I want to separate this to the function, too. Here is my code:

This function is in a Controller, which is extended by my Contoller in which are these actions:

```
protected function findById($id, $class)
{
    $result = $this->getEM()->getRepository('EMMyFriendsBundle:'.$class)->find($id);   
    if($result == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

And this is my Controller:

```
class FriendController extends Controller
{
    private $em;
    private $friend;

    private function init($id)
    {
        $this->em = $this->getEM();
        $this->friend = $this->findById($id, 'Friend');

        if(!$this->friend) {
            return $this->render('EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend:error.html.twig', array(
               'item' => 'friend'));
        }   
    }

    /*
     * Displays all the information about a concrete friend
     */
    public function displayAction($id)
    {
        $this->init($id); 

        if($this->friend->getCategory() != null) {
            $category = $this->friend->getCategory()->getName();
        } else {
            $category = null;
        }

        return $this->render('EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend:friend.html.twig', array(
               'friend' => $this->friend, 'category' => $category));
    }

    // ...
}
```

When I choose an ID, which don't exist (like 38743874) it goes to the if-part in the init function, but doesn't render the template error.html.twig :( But if I take this part

```
if(!$this->friend) {
                return $this->render('EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend:error.html.twig', array(
                   'item' => 'friend'));
            }
```

out of the `init()` function and put it in `displayAction($id)` just after calling `$this->init($id)`, it works. But I don't want to write this in every single action of that controller. Any ideas how to separate it to avoid code duplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return the response of init function. That's why it does show you the error message. You would have to do something like that in `displayAction()`:

```
$response = $this->init();
if ($response) {
    return $response;
}
```